# I can't find the pattern while evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

While integrating:
$$ 
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^nx \, dx
$$
I have noticed that when $n$ is even the value is a multiple of $\pi$, but when $n$ is odd it is rational.

My results are:

- n=1, 1
- n=2, $\frac{\pi}{4}$
- n=3, $\frac{2}{3}$
- n=4, $\frac{3\pi}{16}$
- n=5, $\frac{8}{15}$
- n=6, $\frac{5\pi}{32}$
- n=7, $\frac{16}{35}$
- n=8, $\frac{35\pi}{256}$

and so on...

Is there a pattern? And if so what is it?

Comment: Google "Wallis integral" for how to deal with this. The trick is to find a relationship between the integrals for $n$ and $n+2$ using integration by parts.

Comment: Note that the odd values increase by factors of 2/3, 4/5, 6/7, 8/9, etc. Similarly, the even values (starting with n=0 giving $\pi/2$) gives 1/2, 3/4, 5/6, etc. That's exactly the recursion relation exhibited by J.G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @StefanLafon notes, using integration by parts twice viz.$$\int_0^{\pi/2}uv^{\prime\prime}dx=[uv^\prime]_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2}u^\prime v^\prime \,dx = [uv^\prime-u^\prime v]_0^{\pi/2} + \int_0^{\pi/2} u^{\prime\prime} v \, dx$$with $u=\sin^{n+1}x,\,v=-\sin x$ gives$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+2}x\,dx=[n\sin^{n+1}x\cos x]_0^{\pi/2}-(n+1)\int_0^{\pi/2}(n\sin^nx-(n+1) \sin^{n+2}x) \, dx,$$where we've used $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$. Rearranging,$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+2}x \, dx=\frac{n+1}{n+2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx \, dx.$$You can also write your integral [in terms of the Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas):$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^ndx=\tfrac12\operatorname{B}\left(\tfrac12,\,\tfrac{n+1}{2}\right)=\tfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n+2}{2}\right)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

These are Wallis' integrals : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals

An integration by parts leads to $W_{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}W_n$ therefore $W_{2n}=\frac{(2n)!\pi}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}$ and $W_{2n+1}=\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$.